# go lang json.Marshal notw

Tags: json, http, go

I am struggeling to build a proper json payload for a http request:

```golang
type CreateOrga struct {
    Data struct {
        Type       string `json:"type"`
        Attributes struct {
            Name  string `json:"name"`
            Email string `json:"email"`
        } `json:"attributes"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

    email := "my@mail.com"
    value := CreateOrga{
        Data: {
            Type: "organizations",
            Attributes: { 
                Name: "API", 
                Email: email,
            },
        },
    }
    
    json, _ := json.Marshal(value)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(json))
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
    //  resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", payload)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("An error occured %v", err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
```

However, I always receive `missing ',' before newline in composite literal`.
What am I doing wrong here?
Do I need to build a struct?

Comment: The type `map[string]map[string]string` and your composite literal `{ ... }` are quite out of tune. The composite literal of a map MUST be `{ Key:Value[, ...] }` where both `Key` and `Value` are expressions that evaluate to their corresponding types. For starters, your first element in the composite map literal has *NO* `Key`.

Comment: Another problem in your composite literal is the fact that in the nested map you defined the value's type as `string`, but you actually try to nest another map in it. If you want the values of a map to accept strings & other maps then you have to declare the value's type as `interface{}` instead of `string`.

Comment: ok, thanks. Most likely I need to build a `struct` first and the marshaln it, right?

Comment: It's doable with maps, but structs are a much nicer approach in my biased opinion.

Comment: same issue with `struct`. How would you write the code?

Comment: Update the question with the new code that is failing and I may suggest a fix.

Comment: Go does not support eliding the type, anonymous or not, in struct composite literals. i.e. `Data: {` and `Attributes: {` are *invalid*. The `{` is missing a type in front. With anonymous struct types such composite literals are a pain to initialize. Therefore, the common suggestion is not to use anonymous struct types in fields that you plan to initialize with a composite literal.

Comment: Ok. Difficult to follow you as I am a beginner in Go xD.
I solved it with 
```value := CreateOrga{}
 value.Data.Type = "organizations"
 value.Data.Attributes.Name = "API"
 value.Data.Attributes.Email = email```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/6SFqiU0IeO1 -- `A` is using a named struct type for field `F` and is easy to initialize with a composite literal. `A2` is using an anonymous struct type for field `F` and is therefore much more of a pain to initialize with the composite literal, because you need to repeat the anonymous type's definition.